# How to create private key from SSL certificate?

Tags: windows, apache, ssl, certificate, private-key

I want to create private for ssl certificate which is in CER format. I have CER format certificate and PKCS #7 certificate with that.

are private key available on-server only or do we get them  with certificate separately? 
 i am working with Apache on windows

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description you have only the certificate. This certificate contains the public key. You cannot create a private key from it because of how [Public Key Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) works.

If you could create the private key from any certificate you could essentially authenticate yourself as an arbitrary server on the internet and man in the middle attacks would be easy. Thus, it is good that you cannot get a private key from a certificate.

Comment: how would i get PRIVATE KEY for my certificate then do i need to request to team separately?   who has provided me ssl certificate  @steffenUllrich

Comment: @DivyanxiMistry: I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly. But - whoever has you provided with the certificate should have provided you with the private key too if you should use this certificate as a server certificate.